# Using getter/setter for splitting a url

Tags: c#

I have a url, for example: http://mywebsite.com/another/andanother/test.php I want to be able to split it by `/` so I can access it in an array like so:

```
identify[0];
identify[1];
```

I have a getter and setter like so:

```
p
```

How can I achieve what I am looking for?

I get the following error when I try running

> Cannot convert string to char

Comment: Please explain why your approach doesn't work. Apart from the compile error (remove the .ToString()), what are you seeing compared and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: A `string[]` is not a `string` so the above makes no sense.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  How do you want to access this property?

Comment: Your `set` does not make sense. You don't ever use the keyword `value` in it. It looks like it would make a lot more sense to have a `get` only and in that get look at the text and split it.

Comment: Your recent edit has made your question unclear. You need to fix it or risk it being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, with lazy loading:

```
private string[] _identify;
public string[] identify
{
    get
    {
        if (_identify == null)
        {
            _identify = url.Text.Split('/');
        }
        return _identify;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the existing [Uri class]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.113).aspx) provides what you need.

This:

```
var uri = new Uri(
    "http://scotthannen.org/blog/2017/04/26/dependency-inversion-for-beginners.html");
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsolutePath);
```

returns

> /blog/2017/04/26/dependency-inversion-for-beginners.html

which you can split by "/".

This:

```
var uri = new Uri(
    "http://scotthannen.org/blog/2017/04/26/dependency-inversion-for-beginners.html");
foreach(var segment in uri.Segments)
{
    Console.WriteLine(segment);
}
```

returns

> /
>   blog/
>   2017/
>   04/
>   26/
>   dependency-inversion-for-beginners.html

And there are all sorts of other helpful properties and methods for working with urls so you don't have to use all sorts of `string` methods to parse them.